# What would the best way to pull this multi column data into one column but copying adjacent cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to get my data from this:

[image: What it currently is]

to this:

[image: What i want it to be]
without doing it manually.
I should have shown in the first screenshot that there are multiple rows of similar data as show below.

[image: Actual data]

As Brian said I am trying to get columns A:F into a single column (a "new A column) and then copy contents from columns G:H to the two columns (a "new "B:C") next to each entry in the new A column

Comment: What *have* you tried and where is the problem, exactly? Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1440228/edit) to let us know

Comment: Are you trying to get columns A:F into a single column (a "new A column) and then copy contents from columns G:H to the two columns (a "new "B:C") next to each entry in the new A column?

Comment: Just use Power Query and Unpivot the first three columns.

Comment: @Brian Yes that's exactly it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ron Rosenfeld's suggestion to Unpivot Columns is a good solution. I actually had to learn it myself so I must also thank Ron. Here is how it applies to your problem.

Please remember to mark this as an answer if it solves your problem.

1. Add a header entry to each column (this is option but a good practice - you can always delete from your end result).

[image]

2. Go to the "Data" tab in Excel. Click "From Table/Range"

[image]

3. Power Query Editor will open up. Select the first 6 columns (hold down ctrl while clicking each column or hold down shift and click the first column and then the last column).
4. Right click on one of the column headers and left click on "Unpivot Columns" in the context menu.

[image]

5. Click "Close & Load"

[image]

Here is your final product. If you don't want information in column C (the headers), you can delete it. Also, you can rearrange columns to suit your desired output layout.

[image]